# Real-time streaming of an MP4 file

Tags: php, javascript, flash, mp4, flowplayer

How to play mp4 videos in e.g. flowplayer in real-time (streaming) - without downloading it fully first?

Comment: google...(stream mp4) first result: http://all-streaming-media.com/streaming-media-faq/faq-mp4-streaming.htm

Answer (score 0):

We use Wowza Streaming Media Server - http://www.wowzamedia.com/

You'll need to do a whole bunch of work though to get it up and running etc, but there are lots of examples out there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this one?
[Using Flowplayer to Stream Videos](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/bits-on-the-run/15971/using-flowplayer-to-stream-videos)

There are some code samples and links to Flowplayer but check it out if that's what you're looking for.